# Google Map is not getting displayed in xcode5

Tags: ios, google-maps, xcode5

I am using xcode 5, I am creating a map view using google map api, using the link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start#getting_the_google_maps_sdk_for_ios
i am using google maps SDK 1.7.0.
When I move to the mapView, in my log, it is getting printed as

```
Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0xc540670 </Users/wifin/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/5C049949-8859-4542-A434-F35A3A193356/MaaramaWines.app/GoogleMaps.bundle/GMSCoreResources.bundle> (not loaded)

Google Maps SDK for iOS version: 1.7.0.7198
```

But, the map is not getting displayed in the view, can anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

Try use `[self.view addSubview mapView_];` at the end of - (void)viewDidLoad; in this example

Comment: thank u, i got it, the mistake was, i was trying to add the ma in a small custom viewe, i gave the size as CGRectZero, now i changed it, it works now